# The easiest way to format string like 1 000 000

Tags: java, android, string

In my android program I display big numbers. To make them easy-reading I want to format these numbers not like **1000000** but like **1 000 000**.

Which is the easiest way to format strings like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
String s = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(1000000);
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this `Locale` :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with [`Locale#US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) to add `,`s to the number:

```
String myNumber = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(number);
```

And then replace every `,` with a space:

```
myNumber = myNumber.replace(",", " ");
```

---

Or, as @EvgeniyDorofeev suggested, use `Locale#FRANCE` and you won't have to replace anything :)

---

Please note the difference between `replace` and `replaceAll`. See [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) that accepts a [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and please try the code.

They **both replace all characters**, `replaceAll` accepts a *regex*, which I **don't need** in this case.

Comment: Its it should be replaceAll?

Comment: @Zeeshan No. `replace` will be fine here.. Try it.

Comment: What is the difference between `replace` and `replaceAll`?

Comment: @ylun the latter accept *regex* as an argument. But they're both *replace all*.

Comment: @Zeeshan **No**, refer to the docs please and please try the snippet I posted.

Comment: Got it `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` also accepts `String` as method argument as `String` implements `CharSequence`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like so,

```
long num = 1000000;
System.out.println(String.format("%,d", num).replace(",", " "));
```

Output is

```
1 000 000
```